# Cannot determine GraphQL output type for 'books' of 'Bible' class. Is the value, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper output value?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, graphql, typegraphql, mikro-orm

For background, I am using MikroOrm and type-graphql on MongoDB

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Bible {
  @Field(() => ID)
  @PrimaryKey()
  _id!: ObjectId;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  name!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  abbreviation!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  language!: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  lang!: string;

  @Field(() => [Book])
  @Embedded(() => Book, { array: true })
  books!: Book[];
}
```

I create my class and in the property "books" I set it to an array of the class Book. Here is the class Book.

```
@Embeddable()
export class Book {
  @Field(() => String)
  @Property()
  name: string;

  @Field(() => [Chapter])
  @Embedded(() => Chapter, { array: true })
  chapters: Chapter[];

  constructor(name: string, chapters: Chapter[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.chapters = chapters;
  }
}
```

The error occurs on @Field(() => [Book]) according to type-graphql documentation this is correct, please help.

Comment: Maybe you need `@ObjectType()` on the `Book` class as well?

Answer (score 0):

As Martin Adámek mentioned, you need `@ObjectType()` on the Book class too. Otherwise, GraphQL cannot recognize the class.

Comment: Thank you very much for this definitely solved it for me. Now I need to figure out how to ignore some of the nested objects so that it diminishes the time for fetching.